# Stuck on how to "append a period" into an acronym

Tags: java, acronym

An acronym is a word formed from the initial letters of words in a set phrase. Define a method named createAcronym that takes a string parameter and returns the acronym of the string parameter. Append a period (.) after each letter in the acronym. If a word begins with a lower case letter, don't include that letter in the acronym. Then write a main program that reads a phrase from input, calls createAcronym() with the input phrase as argument, and outputs the returned acronym. Assume the input has at least one upper case letter.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers
```

the output should be:

```
I.E.E.E.
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
Association for computing MACHINERY
```

the output should be:

```
A.M.
```

The letters ACHINERY in MACHINERY don't start a word, so those letters are omitted.

The program must define and call a method:

```
public static String createAcronym(String userPhrase)
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
     public static String createAcronym(String userPhrase) {

       String[] separatedWords = userPhrase.split(" ");

       String acronymAlphabets = " ";

       for(int i = 0; i < separatedWords.length; ++i) {

           if(Character.isUpperCase(separatedWords [i].charAt(0))) {

               acronymAlphabets += Character.toUpperCase(separatedWords [i].charAt(0));

           }

       }

       return acronymAlphabets;

   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println(createAcronym(userInput.nextLine()));
   }
}
```

The system returns the correct acronym but cant for the life of me figure out how to get the periods in the proper place. Side note: Im really good at getting them at the beginning or end of them. Any help "appending" this problem would be awesome!

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent advice! Being a complete noob to java I learned a couple new techniques!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change
`acronymAlphabets += Character.toUpperCase(separatedWords [i].charAt(0));`
to
`acronymAlphabets += Character.toUpperCase(separatedWords [i].charAt(0))+".";`

Here is one way using streams.

```
String[] titles = {"Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers",     
    "Association for Computing MACHINERY",
    "Association of  Lions, and Tigers, and Bears, oh my!!"};

for (String title : titles) {
    System.out.println(createAcronym(title));
}
```

prints

```
I.E.E.E
A.C.M
A.L.T.B
```

- Split on anything that isn't a word and stream the array
- filter any words not starting with an upper case character.
- Map the first letter of each word to a String.
- and join together with a period between each word.

```
public static String createAcronym(String title) {
    return Arrays.stream(title.split("\\W+"))
            .filter(str -> Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0)))
            .map(str -> str.substring(0, 1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("."));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that will include a starting letter if it is capitalized, and tack on a period (".") after any included letters.

A few comments:

- Line 3: a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is an efficient, powerful way to make small additions to a String
- Line 5: use a "for" loop over the words (from line 2)
- Line 6: isolate the starting character of "word"
- Line 8: if firstChar is upper case, go ahead and append it to the StringBuilder result (no need to uppercase it again – it is already upper case or we wouldn't have made to line 8); and any time we append a letter, always go ahead and append a ".", too
- Line 12: once we're done with all of the words, conver the StringBuilder to a String, and return the result

```
1.  public static String createAcronym(String input) {
2.     String[] words = input.split(" ");
3.     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
4.
5.     for (String word : words) {
6.         char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
7.         if (Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)) {
8.              result.append(firstChar).append(".");
9.         }
10.    }
11.
12.    return result.toString();
13. }
```

You could further improve this by editing Line 2: instead of calling [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with a single space (`" "`), you could instead use a regular expressions to split on any number of whitespaces, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just need to append a period (.) after each letter.

Add the following line at the end of the loop.

```
acronymAlphabets += ".";
```

Footnote: I would say the Answer offered by Kaan above using `StringBuilder` is better. I have offered an Answer making minimal chances to the code in the question. Given the OP is a novice I believe it's unhelpful to introduce too many new ideas in a reply.
In programming and Java there's usually a dozen ways to do anything. Bombarding novices with new concepts only confuses them. One step at a time if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Other Answers, such as the [one by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102725/642706), give a direct, correct solution to the specifics of the Question: appending `.` to each capital letter. My Answer here is more for fun.

## tl;dr

Using code points rather than `char`.

```java
System.out.println(
        String.join(   // Join a bunch of strings into a single `String` object.
                "" ,   // Join the strings without any delimiter between them.
                Arrays.stream(  // Turn an array into a stream of elements for processing.
                                "Association of  Lions, and Tigers, and Bears, oh my!!"
                                        .split( " " )  // Returns an array of string objects, `String[]`. 
                        )
                        .filter( ( String part ) -> ! part.isBlank() )  // Skip any string elements without significant text.
                        .map( ( String part ) -> part.codePoints().boxed().toList() )  // Generate a stream of `int` integer numbers representing the code point numbers of each character in the string element. Via boxing, convert those `int` primitives into `Integer` objects. Collect the `Integer` objects into a `List`. 
                        .filter( ( List < Integer > codePoints ) -> Character.isUpperCase( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) )  // Skip any list of code points if the first code point represents a character other than an uppercase letter. 
                        .map( ( List < Integer > codePoints ) -> Character.toString( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) + "." )  // Extract the first code point `Integer` number, turn into a `String` containing the single character represented by that code point, and append a FULL STOP. 
                        .toList()  // Collect all those generated strings (single character plus FULL STOP) to a list.
        )
);
```

> A.L.T.B.

## Code points

I recommend making a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers rather than the legacy `char` type. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

This code makes heavy use of streams. If not yet comfortable with streams, you could replace with conventional loops.

Pull apart the phrase.

```java
    System.out.println( "input = " + input );
    String[] parts = input.split( " " );
    if ( parts.length == 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Input must consist of multiple words separated by spaces." ); }
    System.out.println( "parts = " + Arrays.toString( parts ) );
```

Convert each part of the phrase into code point integer numbers.

```java
    List < List < Integer > > codePointsOfEachPart =
            Arrays
                    .stream( parts )
                    .filter( part -> ! part.isBlank() )
                    .map( part -> part.codePoints().boxed().toList() )
                    .toList();
```

Filter for those parts of the phrase that begin with an uppercase letter. From each of the qualifying parts, extract the first letter, append a FULL STOP, and collect to a list.

```java
    List < String > abbreviations =
            codePointsOfEachPart
                    .stream()
                    .filter( ( List < Integer > codePoints ) -> Character.isUpperCase( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) )
                    .map( codePoints -> Character.toString( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) + "." )
                    .toList();

    // Join the collection of UppercaseLetter + FULL STOP combos into a single piece of text.
    String result = String.join( "" , abbreviations );

    return result;
}
```

When run:

```
input = Association of  Lions, and Tigers, and Bears, oh my!!
parts = [Association, of, , Lions,, and, Tigers,, and, Bears,, oh, my!!]
output = A.L.T.B.
```

---

Pull that all together for your copy-paste convenience.

```java
private String acronym ( final String input )
{
    // Pull apart the phrase.
    System.out.println( "input = " + input );
    String[] parts = input.split( " " );
    if ( parts.length == 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Input must consist of multiple words separated by spaces." ); }
    System.out.println( "parts = " + Arrays.toString( parts ) );

    // Convert each part of the phrase into code point integer numbers.
    List < List < Integer > > codePointsOfEachPart =
            Arrays
                    .stream( parts )
                    .filter( part -> ! part.isBlank() )
                    .map( part -> part.codePoints().boxed().toList() )
                    .toList();

    // Filter for those parts of the phrase that begin with an uppercase letter.
    // From each of the qualifying parts, extract the first letter, append a FULL STOP, and collect to a list.
    List < String > abbreviations =
            codePointsOfEachPart
                    .stream()
                    .filter( ( List < Integer > codePoints ) -> Character.isUpperCase( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) )
                    .map( codePoints -> Character.toString( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) + "." )
                    .toList();

    // Join the collection of UppercaseLetter + FULL STOP combos into a single piece of text.
    String result = String.join( "" , abbreviations );

    return result;
}
```

---

That code could be shortened, into a single line of code! Not that I necessarily recommend doing so.

```java
System.out.println(
        String.join(
                "" ,
                Arrays.stream(
                                "Association of  Lions, and Tigers, and Bears, oh my!!"
                                        .split( " " )
                        )
                        .filter( part -> ! part.isBlank() )
                        .map( part -> part.codePoints().boxed().toList() )
                        .filter( ( List < Integer > codePoints ) -> Character.isUpperCase( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) )
                        .map( codePoints -> Character.toString( codePoints.get( 0 ) ) + "." )
                        .toList()
        )
);
```

> A.L.T.B.